# ERROR: (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) You do not currently have an active account selected

Tags: jenkins

I'm new on jenkins, and i try run robo tests with firebase-test-lab on my windows node, which connected to the linux master.
when the tests should begin to run i got message that I need to log-in first to my account, but i have already done this in VM master (i did this with Putty).

[image: Screenshot here]

The message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.firebase.test.android.run) You do not currently have an
>   active account selected. Please run:   `$ gcloud auth login` to obtain
>   new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a different
>   account:   `$ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT` to select an already
>   authenticated account to use.

Please, any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i have found my problem..
I have tried all the time to login my firebase account, via CentOS machine (with use Putty in my windows OS).

**But**, I had to do this in my computer (my Windows OS).

Therefor, I set the path in Enviroments variable, to gCloud directory, and 
via the cmd i run 'gcloud auth login' and it's login my account.
Next time I build my project in Jenkins, it's work!!